# Kendo DatasourceRequest has null values

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

There will be simplified code, similar to my own for desription of problem:
I had this model classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public Child[] Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

There is View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Stihl.UnfairCompetitionWeb.DataLayer.Models.Parent>(Model.Parents)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(e => e.Something);
        foreach (Stihl.UnfairCompetitionWeb.DataLayer.Models.LanguageModel l in Model.Languages)
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.Children[Model.Languages.IndexOf(l)].Title).Title(l.Code).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_language = l.Code });
        }

        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy());
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => {
            toolbar.Create();
            toolbar.Save();
        })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable((p => p.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 20, 50 })))
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(10)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(e => e.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ProductCategories_Read", "Admin"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("ProductCategories_Create", "Admin"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("ProductCategories_Update", "Admin"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ProductCategories_Delete", "Admin"))
    )
)
```

So, on Crud methods on controller, DataSourceRequest properties like Aggregates, Filters, Groups and Sorts are null.

JFI - I use grid by same way on other cases and it works correct.

What is problematic in this case in my opinion - grid columns are bind on items from array. Not on some simple properties of model class. There was more problems with it, what i solved yet.

Problem with DataSourceRequest is last. Without it i cant implement paging, sorting, filtering and other functionality, which is normally about one KeyWord on view and siple code on controller.

Is any way how work with it on client side?

PS:
Controller method. But on controller, incoming DataSourceRequest contains described null data.

```
public ActionResult Parents_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(entities.Parents.ToModel(entities.Languages.ActiveLangauges()).ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the aspnetmvc script is loaded? Also how does the controller look like?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. On controller is only problematic incoming data. I add it just for info, but nothing interesting on it - same like in basic example. Problem is that data are not exist on post, so they can't be correct on controller.

Seems that real question is how work with post in Kendo, how owerloaded Sort, filter etc. request.

Comment: obsolate. And wrong question, mistake was somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For solving DataSourceRequest:
I have had the same problem, but I changed **kendo.web.min.js** to **kendo.all.min.js** and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue. i sloved this issue with adding kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js
With this js file request can hit Httppost method.Not httpget method